# Background Image doesn't show right

Tags: css, colors, background-image, gradient

My background Image navbar isn't showing properly. If you notice, the gradient for the navbar doesn't display properly. The top half should be a light gray and the bottom half should be a darker gray. When the page firsts loads you can see it appear but then it all goes gray and loses the gradient look.

My site is [usahvacsupply.com](http://www.usahvacsupply.com/) and I just edited my background-image to be bigger to fit for a 1600 width resolution. Here is a picture of my background image http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=20ge8nl&s=5. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my css code for the background.

```
html, body{
    margin: auto;
    background-image:url('/images/Testing1/bg2.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position:top center;
    -moz-background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    min-width:1600px;
    min-height:1400px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `float:left` on div with ID `lol` seems to fix it.

Comment: Thank you rubelet, that does seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

Your table element `#body` has a background which is obscuring the gradient. Remove it and the gradient in your background appears.

Original

```
#body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Modified

```
#body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh this works as well!